# Create a pdf that does not allow user to save as text

Tags: pdf, text, pdf-generation

I would like to know if there is a way to create a pdf that will not allow users to save as a text document or print the document, but will allow users to add comments and highlighting and save their changes solely in the pdf format.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> "I would like to know if there is a way to create a pdf that will not
>   allow users to save as a text document"

Sure, you have several options, you can configure embedded fonts so that they don't contain text-related information (for a example using CID fonts that don't have a ToUnicode table). Another choice would be to draw all the text with regular PDF drawing operations (lines and curves) instead of using text operators + fonts.

Note that in all scenarions, there is no possible way for you to prevent a user from exporting a PDF into a bitmap and applying an OCR software on the resulting images.

> "or print the document,"

This is one is a bit more difficult, you will have to add the content that you don't want to be printed as a PDF layer (also called Optional Content Group), and then configure this layer as display-only.
Note that here you will be relying on the PDF viewer to respect these settings, as a user I might be able to find a PDF viewer that prints everything nevertheless.

> "but will allow users to add comments and highlighting"

No problem there

> and save their changes solely in the pdf format.

I can say without fear to be mistaken that this is one is impossible to achieve... You have no control whatsoever on the application a user might have for viewing PDFs, and there is no way you can prevent him from using an application that saves PDF files as PNG or XPS for example.